# Android : Scroll Screen when keyboard showing using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-constraintlayout

I am using `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`with four `EditText` and one `Button`. When clicked on First `Edittext`, `SoftInput Keyboard` visible then `EditText` and `Button` Hidden. 
I tried in `ManiFeast.xml`

1. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
2. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`
3. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"`

But did work.
Any suggestion to make screen scrollable when not using `ScrollView`

its my `Manifest.xml` `Activity` tag

```
    <application
     .
     .
     .
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell when the keyboard is showing.  So what you want isn't possible.  What you can do is stick the whole thing in a ScrollView so its always scrollable.  Then it will still be scrollable when the keyboard is up.